# Ошибка при сборке проекта: Deployment error: Cannot invoke "String.isEmpty()"

Tags: java, servlet, netbeans

Пытаюсь создать небольшую Web приложение для лабораторной работы с использованием Servlet, но при сборке проекта в NetBeans 19 возникает ошибка Deployment error: Cannot invoke "String.isEmpty()" because "path" is null

Не подскажете откуда могут расти ноги, посмотрел весь код, вроде нигде не замечен String.isEmpty()

ControllerServlet

```
import DAO.UserDAO;
import DAO.ProductDAO;
import Models.User;
import Models.Product;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private UserDAO userDAO;
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        userDAO = new UserDAO();
        productDAO = new ProductDAO();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = req.getParameter("action");
        if (action == null) {
            action = "list";
        }
        switch (action) {
            case "create":
                showCreateForm(req, resp);
                break;
            case "list":
            default:
                listUsersAndProducts(req, resp);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = req.getParameter("action");
        switch (action) {
            case "create":
                createUserAndProduct(req, resp);
                break;
            default:
                resp.sendRedirect("ControllerServlet?action=list");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showCreateForm(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/create.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

    private void createUserAndProduct(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        String userName = req.getParameter("userName");
        String productName = req.getParameter("productName");

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userName);
        userDAO.save(user);

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName(productName);
        productDAO.save(product);

        resp.sendRedirect("ControllerServlet?action=list");
    }

    private void listUsersAndProducts(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("users", userDAO.getAll());
        req.setAttribute("products", productDAO.getAll());
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/list.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

ProductDAO

```
package DAO;
import Models.Product;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ProductDAO implements DAO<Product> {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public ProductDAO() {
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/javadao");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Product save(Product product) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Product (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setInt(1, product.getId());
            statement.setString(2, product.getName());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return product;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Product product) {
        String sql = "UPDATE Product SET name = ? WHERE id = ?";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setString(1, product.getName());
            statement.setInt(2, product.getId());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Product product) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE id = ?";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setInt(1, product.getId());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Product get(int id) {
        Product product = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE id = ?";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                product = new Product();
                product.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                product.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return product;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAll() {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Product";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                product.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                products.add(product);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return products;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> search(String query) {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE name LIKE ?";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setString(1, "%" + query + "%");
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                product.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                products.add(product);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return products;
    }
}
```

UserDAO

```
package DAO;
import Models.User;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class UserDAO implements DAO<User> {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public UserDAO() {
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/javadao");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO User (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setInt(1, user.getId());
            statement.setString(2, user.getName());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        String sql = "UPDATE User SET name = ? WHERE id = ?";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setString(1, user.getName());
            statement.setInt(2, user.getId());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM User WHERE id = ?";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setInt(1, user.getId());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User get(int id) {
        User user = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = ?";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                user = new User();
                user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM User";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> search(String query) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE name LIKE ?";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setString(1, "%" + query + "%");
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/javadao" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="root" password="root" 
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javadao"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Смотри логи, там должна быть подсказка.

Answer (score 0):

Найдите класс, в котором у вас используется переменная path типа String. По логике программы, в неё должен быть записан путь к чему-то (например, к файлу конфигурации БД). Но её значение почему-то null. Отсюда ноги и растут.